# Decision split activity in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a Journey builder with a Salesforce Data Event on the "Opportunity" object. When an Opportunity record is injected into the Journey later in the customer journey process if the Opportunity record owner is inactive, the Opportunity record should exit out from the Journey.

I have created the decision split and the attribute group to configure the condition for inactive user.

Path-1 Condition:

```
IsActive = True AND (Profile.Name='Sales Admin-1' OR Profile.Name='Sales Admin-2')
```

When I tested using the inactive and active user, the opportunity record was taking reminder path in decision split.

Also, I have added the same condition in exit criteria with

```
isActive = 'False' and (Profile.Name='Sales Admin-1' OR Profile.Name='Sales Admin-2')
```

still, the record was not exiting out the journey.

I highly appreciate your help please share me your valuable inputs.

Comment: For understanding purpose, I have provided the condition in a logical way. I just configured the conditions in the decision split. 

The actual steps are:

isActive equals to True AND 
 (Profile.Name equals to Sales Admin-1 OR Profile.Name equals to Sales Admin-2)

Comment: Is your path in the decision split from Contact --> Account --> Opportunity? If there are multiple opportunities for a single contact it may not be referencing the correct one.

Comment: Yes, a single contact will have multiple opportunities. When the Opportunity record reached the decision split this condition isActive equals to True AND (Profile.Name equal to Sales Admin-1 OR Profile.Name equals to Sales Admin-2) was not evaluated in the journey. What would be the next steps for making the inactive user to exit out the journey. 

Can I configure the condition in the exit criteria of the journey builder or in the decision split.